# Java RMI - Remote Deployment

Tags: java, deployment, rmi

I have a locally working JAVA RMI Applicaton(Server & Client).
I have used Eclipse & a plugin(Genady) to write & run these applications.

There are three parts in my project:
1. Server
2. Interface(Common for both client & server)
3. Client

Local deployment, using Eclipse(+plugin), works perfectly. The client uses the common interface(added to the "Build Path") to communicate(to n fro) with the server(which also has the common interface added to its Build Path in eclipse).

And now, I'm planning to test the same system in two different computers, both having Internet connection.
What do I do now?
Should I be installing Apache on one computer(Server) & put the Server+Interface files(class-files) into the web-accessible directory? & then run the Client-files(having both client & interface class files) from another computer(Client)??

Can someone help me configure this? I mean, a step-by-step guide as to what I should be doing in order for the remote deployment to work?

Is using Apache(or any web server application) compulsory?? Any other alternative for my application to work without using a web server(I mean, like direct connection or something?)?

(I feel I've given all the info that is required. But if any more info is needed, please ask.)

This is my final year project & my final demo is coming up soon!
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: You don't need an Apache server unless you are using the codebase feature. The rest of your question is too vague to answer. You need to deploy server classes to the server; client classes to the client; and shared classes to both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Genady does since I rarely use Eclipse.
Developing RMI applications is very easy anyway.

Pack the server code and run it on the remote machine (the R in RMI)(a.k.a. server host), it should register itself with the Registry which by default uses port 1099 but you can create a registry in any port you like:

```
MyRemoteInterface stub = (MyRemoteInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0); //I don't know if this is needed anymore, or you could make the "server" extend UnicastRemoteObject
int thePortUsedInTheServer = 1099; //default
Registry registry = Registry.createRegistry(thePortUsedInTheServer);
registry.rebind("Server", stub));
```

Pack the client code and run it on the client(s) (the M+I in RMI), it should locate the Registry in the remote machine (host+port):

```
String host = ...; //the host where the server is
int port = ...; //the port used in the server
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
MyRemoteInterface stub = (MyRemoteInterface)registry.lookup("Server");
stub.myRemoteMethod(); //call your remote methods
```

The javadoc should help you out. Nothing else is required, no Apache, etc. Watch out for aggresive anti-virus software, firewalls, and the like. Those are the only real issues after you get the gist of it.